# Xamarin android app crashes when resuming

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Apparently our Xamarin native app crashes on Android sometimes after it has not been used for a while, but I haven't been able to reproduce it.

It seems the crash is caused when inflating one of the fragments in our tabbed application. Any idea what this can be? Reports are only for Android 7, though the app have few users so might be a coincidence. The app targets Android 7.0 but previously when the app had target framework set to android 6.0 the error was the same(with a few lines different). Little luck googling.

Update 11/17/2017: I have tried catching the exception (try block around the 2 lines of code you see for BuildingListFragment) and throwing my own, however it is not caught and the same exception shows up in the google play console crash reports. This is still an issue for me, help would be appreciated.

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at AlarmKeeper.Droid.BuildingListFragment.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00028] in <8584c8930bb24ecaa4ab45fc24b599b6>:0
at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_inflater, System.IntPtr native_container, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00020] in <1e89c43d3c7d48b5ba69bfc0b1bdf114>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:fc5b2ba7-0fe0-4b23-b87c-c512566cc5f6 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
at md5446876e046c50288069676734a083198.BuildingListFragment.n_onCreateView (Native Method)
at md5446876e046c50288069676734a083198.BuildingListFragment.onCreateView (BuildingListFragment.java:30)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2248)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1340)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1569)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1636)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:2977)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:192)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:603)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1256)
at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6972)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2937)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Fragment class:

```
public class BuildingListFragment : Fragment
{
    ...

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BuildingListFragment, container, false);

        ...
    }
...
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class TabAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter, IconPagerAdapter
{
    private MainActivity _context;

    public TabAdapter (MainActivity context, FragmentManager p0) : base(p0)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new BuildingListFragment ();
        case 1:
            return AlarmListFragment.NewInstance("active");
        case 2:
            return AlarmListFragment.NewInstance("confirmed");
        case 3:
            return new ProfileFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get{ return 4; }
    }

    ...
}
```

MainActivity:

```
    private TabAdapter _adapter;
    private ViewPager _viewPager;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

            _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.main_view_pager);
            _adapter = new TabAdapter(this, SupportFragmentManager);
            _viewPager.Adapter = _adapter;
            _viewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(this);

            _tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.main_tab_layout);
            TabLayoutHelper.SetupWithViewPager(_tabLayout, _viewPager);

            var activeItem = Intent.GetIntExtra(ArgActiveFragment, 0);
            if (activeItem != 0)
            {
                _viewPager.SetCurrentItem(activeItem, false);
            }
```

BuildingListFragment.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/building_list_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:clickable="true">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/building_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:divider="@color/light_grey"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/no_buildings_in_list"
                android:id="@+id/no_buildings_text"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your project crash when `Activity` is resuming ?

Comment: Resuming activity and fragment works. According to a user he told me this probably happens when not having used the app for some hours.

Comment: This has to do with the Android's tombstoning mechanism. You need to explore how to save the state of your app and then how to recover from that. You might be able to reproduce this issue enabling the option "Don't keep activities" on your phone / emulator.

Comment: I enabled "Don't keep activites" but I'm not reproducing the error.

Comment: Updated the description. Exception not caught.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the `Activity` and attached `Fragment` being destroyed and recreated. You should look into suggestions similar to @nmilcoff already pointed out in the sense that when reconstructing your `Activity` and attached `Fragment`, that it is able to create all your objects cleanly and doesn't require any dependencies to start fresh.

Comment: I don't manually save or try to get anything from the savedInstanceState bundle in MainActivity or the fragment. I tested with Don't keep activites enabled and can see the onDestroy methods being called but it still worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having an issue with this but I found this thread while running into a similar issue; I couldn't get the crash to happen after enabling the "Don't keep activities" option, but I managed to solve that issue by also setting the option "Background process limit" to "At most 1 process".

Comment: It's fixed. There was some value that wasn't being persisted.